# Retrieve whole object in a join instead of just properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, poco

Is there anyway I can get the whole object Platform instead of just the properties in this query, I am using Poco with EF4:

```
var games = (from g in ctx.Games
join p in ctx.Platforms on g.Platform.Id equals p.Id into joinTable
from j in joinTable.DefaultIfEmpty()                             
  select new
     {
       GameId = g.Id,
       Title = g.Title,
       PlatformId = j.Id,
       PlatformShort = j.Platform_short                                 

      });
```

Instead of using PlatformId and PlatformShort I just want to retrieve the whole Platform object (j). Like "Platform = j"

And is there any better way to return a typed collection with out iterating through games first ?

```
foreach (var g in games)
            {
                Game game = new Game();
                game.Platform = new Platform();
                game.Id = g.GameId;
                game.Title = g.Title;
                game.Platform.Id = g.PlatformId;
                game.Platform.Platform_short = g.PlatformShort;                    

                col.Add(game);
            }
```

I tried this instead:

> return
>   ctx.Games.Include("Platform").Take(50).ToList();

ANd now i got same value for all 100 records.

Here is the SQL:

```
FROM   [dbo].[Games] AS [Extent1] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[Platform_short] AS [Platform_short], [Extent2].[Platform_long] AS [Platform_long], [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent2].[Image] AS [Image], [Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], [Extent2].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Platforms] AS [Extent2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Games] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[PlatformId] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[PlatformId] = [Join1].[Id1] LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Platforms] AS [Extent4]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Games] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[Id] = [Extent5].[PlatformId] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[PlatformId] = [Join3].[Id3]
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your application because using `Platform = j` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a better way:

```
var collection = context.Games.Include("Platform").ToList();
```

Comment: When I am using your approach I get this error:
Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
Any ideas ?

Comment: How is your model defined. Is `Platform` navigation property on `Game`? If yes this must work and it is right way to do that.

Comment: yes Platform is a navigation property on Game.
Maybe it's to much data to handle ? I got like 30000+ records.

Comment: When i am debugging it kind of stops at this point:
IList<Game> test = ctx.Games.Include("Platform").ToList(); And not returning anything. And my computer starts working hard!

Comment: Add stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Btw. why do you want to load 30.000+ records?

Comment: i don't .. i just want to load 100 at a time, but now i'm just trying to get it to work.

Comment: So use `Take()` (and if needed also `Skip()`) to get just 100 records to check if it works.

Comment: Yea it almost worked .. but i got same values for all 100 records.

Comment: And are you sure that your database contains different values? Because both your query with `join` and my query with `Include` should work. If it returns incorrect data you should first check your database.

Comment: yes i am sure .. i got 30000+ values and all are different .. 
and so are the 100 first. It worked fine with the "JOIN" but not this way.

Comment: Do you now how to capture SQL query? Can you check that the query is correct?

Comment: No it didn't work with join because you couldn't call `Platform = j` which should be possible.

Comment: Maybe there are some mapping problem ? Do I need to have Game obj on Platform as a navigation property as well ?

Comment: I put SELECT TOP(100) and now I get the same values as in the code = duplicates.

Comment: Is it 1:N relation (I mean single platform can be related to many Games)? Because in such case the result will be correct. If the first platform is related to more then 100 Games it can return 100 records with the same platform.

Comment: Yes, you are right .. I found the error it was the mapping in the EDM.
It was mapped as 1:1 and it should've been 1:N. Sorry! Thank you for your patient!